# How to Debug Cloud Function? functions.logger.log not Working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When user update `chat/{id}` documents, this function will execute.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.onChangedChat = functions.firestore
.document('chat/{id}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    functions.logger.log("START!!!");
    
    ... some code ...
});
```

However, the function ends with error. So now I'm trying to find the cause of the error but `functions.logger.log` isn't displayed in Firebase Console.

About above example. When the function is called, Log `"START!!!"` should displayed.
Just shows me like below:

> onChangedChat: Function execution started

> onChangedChat: Function execution took 16 ms. Finished with status: error

Where is `"START!!!"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If errors occurs, all logs won't displayed.
After commented out `... some code ...`, `functions.logger.log()` worked.